# How to read a Power Point Presentation in C# without using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application" and Power Point

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I don't want to use **Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application** way to read a Power Point Presentation, Is there any other way to read the contents of slides and embedd the audio into slides as shapes

Comment: Use [OpenXML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/presentations)

Comment: Can you share any code snippet to insert audio in a slde ?

Comment: No, I have nothing prepared but it doesn't look too complicated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.presentation.audio?view=openxml-2.8.1 as that node is supported in the SDK, You can always create a powerpoint with audio, save it, open the file with winzip / 7-zip (or rename the file to .zip) and then look at the content files to workout what that element needs to look like.

Comment: Check Spire.Presentation for .NET: [Insert audio to PowerPoint document](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Presentation/Spire.Presentation-Program-Guide/Audio-and-Video/Insert-audio-to-PowerPoint-document-at-specified-position-in-C-VB.NET.html) example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/net/) instead. This library provides many features for managing presentation contents. The following code example shows you how to add an audio file to a presentation and set some options for it:

```cs
using var presentation = new Presentation();

// Get the first slide.
var slide = presentation.Slides[0];

// Add a sound file as an Audio Frame to the first slide.
using var soundStream = new FileStream("Sound.wav", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var audioFrame = slide.Shapes.AddAudioFrameEmbedded(200, 100, 30, 30, soundStream);

// Play the sound loudly automatically across all slides.
audioFrame.Volume = AudioVolumeMode.Loud;
audioFrame.PlayMode = AudioPlayModePreset.Auto;
audioFrame.PlayAcrossSlides = true;

presentation.Save("EmbeddedSound.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
```

This is a paid product, but you can get a temporary license to evaluate all features for your purposes. Alternatively, you can use [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for .NET](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/net/). The code example below shows you how to do the same using Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```cs
var slidesApi = new SlidesApi("my_client_key", "my_client_secret");

const string pptFileName = "EmbeddedSound.pptx";

slidesApi.CreatePresentation(pptFileName);

// Prepare a data transfer object for an Audio Frame.
var soundData = File.ReadAllBytes("Sound.wav");
var audioFrame = new AudioFrame
{
    X = 200,
    Y = 100,
    Width = 30,
    Height = 30,
    Base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(soundData),
    Volume = AudioFrame.VolumeEnum.Loud,
    PlayMode = AudioFrame.PlayModeEnum.Auto,
    PlayAcrossSlides = true
};

// Add the Audio Frame to the first slide of the presentation.
slidesApi.CreateShape(pptFileName, 1, audioFrame);
```

This is also a paid product that provides a REST API for managing presentations, but you can make 150 free API calls per month for your purposes. I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.